# How to migration existing V1 Json data-factory template to V2 version and use the MS migration tool

Tags: azure-data-factory

Have requirement to migrate the Azure data factory v1 jobs to V2 version.Tried using the existing migration tool by MS its not working giving error.Need help and advice ,how to achieve the migration and what best option or approach can be followed .Also any way to validate the Json template before deployment.

Tried with the MS v1 to v2 tool.Its giving error can't covert also tried directly connecting portal by tool.. same error. Any powershell script or other method where can divide the json and make it v2 format and validate same quickly.

Suggest the best practice or method to be followed.Any existing case study or reference which done this activity will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research and this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c540366-2ddc-4c00-82a6-ffa1abd632dc/upgrade-data-factory-v1-to-v2?forum=AzureDataFactory),it seems that only v1 to v2 migration tool could be chosen so far.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compare-versions) for more on the differences between V1 and V2, and ADF V2 offers richer control flow, authoring, and monitoring capabilities.

If you crashed into error while using the tool, the migration tool allows for direct feedback to be submitted in the tool itself.

[image]

More details, please refer to this [blog](https://azuredatafactoryv2.github.io/v1tov2migration/).

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for the  reply. Will try to look into same and post in the feedback on the issue for help. As per reference document post conversion multiple setup dataset, linked service and pipeline will get.. where we might need to modify the parameter as  replaced with hard code value and Linked service credential need to be changed and parameterized. please help & guide any steps to followed to do that or manually need to do same. Also how to deploy the ARM Json code to portal like using vsts if we want ,any reference ps script there or how to achieve deployment.Thanks for help.